# @EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories based on profile?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-autoconfiguration

I would like to have `@EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories` enabled only when the specific profile is present.

In Kotlin Bean DSL I can define the following condition:

```kotlin
    environment(
        { activeProfiles.contains("local") },
        {
            bean<...>()
            // ...
        }
    )
```

I would like to have the same condition when `@EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories` is present.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate configuration class and use the `@Profile` annotation to inject it only for a requested profile, like this.

```
@Profile("prod")
@EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories
@Configuration
class SomeConfig {
    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        println("I'm here!")
    }
}
```